# Mean function providing rank order output in R

Tags: r, mean, numeric

Dear StackOverflow Users,

R treating a particular data sets as non-numeric, a fairly normal problem:

```
df

 trial   count
 1       0.75   
 2       .
 3       0.90
 4       0.80
```

So I removed the . trials with the subset command:

```
 df <- subset(df, count != '.')
```

Which provides the following output:

```
 trial   count
 1       0.75   
 3       0.90
 4       0.80
```

I want to calculate the mean average of count so I do the following,

```
mean(as.numeric(df$count))
```

But for some reason instead of getting mean of all the values (.816), I get the mean of the rank order values (2).

I have never come across this problem, and though I can think of plenty of work arounds, I was wondering if anyone knew why this was happening?

Thank you for your time and consideration,

BC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `.` changes the column type from `numeric` to `character` (or `factor`).  In this case, it seems to be `factor`.  We need to convert to `character` first and then to `numeric`.

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(df$count)))
```

Otherwise, what we get is the integer storage values of `factor` by directly coercing to `numeric`.  E.g.

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- factor(sample(c(7, 19, 5, 3, 20), 20, replace = TRUE))
as.integer(v1)
#[1] 4 4 1 2 1 5 4 1 5 4 1 4 1 1 4 5 3 3 2 3
as.numeric(as.character(v1))
#[1] 19 19  3  5  3 20 19  3 20 19  3 19  3  3 19 20  7  7  5  7
```